# Simple auth method for a Flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I work on my simple blogging system written in Python, Flask and SQLite,
and I've created a simple authorization system for it. There is no need for anything fancy, so it's just a matter of sending login and password through a form and setting a flag in Flask's session. I wanted to know how things like this are done, so I didn't use any modules.

I'm wondering if this method is correct and secure just enough.

```
# from auth module
@auth.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    """Login as blog admin."""

    # Successeful login conditions
    user_is_valid = request.form['user'] == current_app.config['USER']
    password_is_valid = request.form['password'] == current_app.config['PASSWORD']
    trap_is_empty = not request.form['trap']

    # Login user if credentials are correct
    if user_is_valid and password_is_valid and trap_is_empty:
        session['is_admin'] = True
        return redirect(url_for('admin.posts_page'))
    else:
        return render_template('auth.html')


# from admin module
@admin.before_request
def before_request():
    """ Before any request check admin flag, redirect to the main page if there is none. """
    if not session.get('is_admin'):
        return redirect(url_for('blog.index_page'))
    proj.db.connect()
```

Comment: Other than the fact that your password will be stored in plaintext in the config file, it looks ok for a basic login.

In the future, I would recommend posting code review-type questions like this in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @BrianKH I guess you're right, next time I'll post questions like this at CodeReview. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It honestly looks fine for just a basic authentication system. The bad part is storing the credentials in the config.

If you want to get all cool and fancy, you can use `itsdangerous` to generate hashes and salts of passwords and store them in your sqlite database.

Typically, you'd have a table with id, username, password, and a boolean flag like "is_admin" or something that you can check when you authenticate.

So, it's fine for some playing around, but I wouldn't recommend anything like this in production.

Comment: Also note, that the default flask sessions implementation stores all session data in cookies. So, you are slightly exposing credentials implementation details by placing `is_admin` flag to session.

Comment: @Ostrovski, you would not place an `is_admin` flag in the session, but in the database. So, whenever you visit an admin link, it checks your user against the database.

Also, if you use a proper secret key, you should have no issue with storing that kind of information inside of the session data.

Comment: @Tux, while I agree that hashing password would be preferrable, I think there's no need for DB in this case. Python files would not be accessible directly from web, and my DB is a SQLite file. So if project files are compromised password would be exposed anyway.

Comment: @Ostrovski Thanks, didn't know that!

Comment: @Tux, so generally it would be better to store `user_id` in the session, right? My system is single user only, but it's a good advice anyway, thanks.

Comment: For persistent access to an admin panel or something, you can store a Boolean flag in the session. Just make sure your secret key is strong enough to not be cracked.

Comment: Tux, Ostrovski Thank you for your help, now I know how to improve my code :) Marking question as solved.